# How can I get the historical data of stocks being ranked in Zacks Investment?

Tags: historical-data

I am looking at Zacks Stock Market Research web site and it has rankings for stocks like 'Sell', 'Buy', 'Strong Sell', 'Hold' etc.

I would like to retrieve historical data of the stock rankings going back a year.
Has anyone tried that before ?

I'd appreciate if some one could shed light on how to do it ?
I am open to using command line tools like Bash, Curl, Perl or Python and using REST APIs to do it.

Comment: Are you seeking the historical rankings or the historical share price data as suggested in Leon's answer?

Comment: @BobBaerker : Thanks for replying. I am looking at Historical Rating, (not historical share price )

The Zack's web site states the historical Rating for every stock. It could be a 'Buy', 'Strong Buy', 'Sell, 'Strong Sell', and 'Hold'.

The problem I see in this is, let's say I pick a stock and view it's rating and it could be a 'Buy', However it held a 'Buy' rating from last few weeks, and in that case I'd like to go back in History and see 'since when was this holding a 'Buy' Rating.' as this rating could be getting stale shortly !.
That's why I was hoping to see Historical Ratings date

Comment: incredible, but http://web.archive.org/ works. for example you enter and see when the page https://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/ZM change and what was rating. Theoretically, you could write a script to collect all the ranks to back test your ideas.

Answer (score 3):

I dont think a deep implementation like what you suggest (command line tools or API calls) is needed for this purpose.

Just head over to [finance.yahoo.com](http://finance.yahoo.com) and you ll be able to get historical data, or export them as CSV if you want to process them, through its interface.
(if you need something more extreme than just a quick look, an API is also offered to programmatically query)

**EDIT**: If you need the specific web content, as in the recommendations given by them on specific dates, you can use a service like http://web.archive.org/  to check the site's content during that time. Doubt anyone will have extensive archives at hands for the specific site's recommendations per se, so I think that's the best shot you have.